# Teapot Riddle: my first is fragile, my second isn't fragile but tough

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle rules:
I have **one** word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my clues.

*Let's get started!*

First clue:

> My first teapot is fragile
>   My second teapot isn't fragile but tough

Second clue:

> Music is attached to my first teapot
>   My second teapot is attachable to everything

Third clue:

> My first teapot is like an ancient technology (though it isn't).
>   My second teapot is a way older technology, but is even nowadays commonly used.

Final clue:

> My first teapot was replaced by the CD.
>  My second teapot is the stickiest tool you find in your house.

Comment: When is teapot going to be its own tag?

Comment: look up teapot riddle no 1, i had a comment with someone who konows that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you:

> Tape

And more specifically:

> Cassette/VHS Tape and Duct/sticky tape

Comment: When did you find out?

Comment: Honestly, the final hint

Answer (score 6):

is it

> tape  (cassette and adhesive)

First

> a cassette tape is fragile, adhesive tape is stronger (or can be)

Second

> Music on a cassette tape is common, adhesive tape attaches to all

Third

> Cassette tapes are ancient (to kids today), adhesive tape has been around a long time

Final

> cassette tape replaced by CD, Adhesive tape is sticky

Comment: AHKieran beat you to it! Ill upvote both answers though and you have an explanition

Answer (score 3):

I think the teapot is:

> Record(s) - i.e. Vinyl records and World Records

First Hint:

> Drop a vinyl record, it'll likely break, they are easy to chip, etc.
> It is hard to break a world record, you need to be an elite athlete (for example)

Second Hint:

> A vinyl contains music
> Records can be attached to anything, even dumb things.

Third Hint:

> There are manyold formats similar to the vinyl records, maybe stretch, but like the [Piano roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_roll) 
> (Note: I guess I misread this one since my answer isn't correct) Records are a historically kept, much longer than most technology still in use.

Final Hint:

> The CD is a more modern vinyl.
> Siblings fight over "records," causing fights? (This one is definitely a stretch)

Comment: no , but also cool teapot

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely realized I had to make some huge leaps to make it works, but it's more fun than the answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a

> Tape

First teapot:

> Magnetic tape used in audio cassettes. It is fragile, contains music, looks ancient nowadays and audio CDs replaced it

Second teapot:

> A duct tape. It is tough, sticky, old and can be found in every house